# How to create function in phpMyadmin mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this code to create a function in db mysql using PHP:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnStripTags;
    DELIMITER |
    CREATE FUNCTION fnStripTags( Dirty varchar(4000) )
    RETURNS varchar(4000)
    DETERMINISTIC 
    BEGIN
      DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
        WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
          BEGIN
            SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
            SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
            IF iLength > 0 THEN
              BEGIN
                SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
              END;
            END IF;
          END;
        END WHILE;
        RETURN Dirty;
    END;
    |
    DELIMITER
```

Well, is not working, so i would like to know how to create this function in phpMyadmin.
I know i have to change some things like adding $$ but i don't know how or where.

I'm not an expert in mysql :/

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @Philipp When i do it in PHP i don't get any error, but it doesn't work...

Comment: can you try it directly via mysql console?

Answer (score 0):

First, verify the syntax is correct (perhaps running it through a different client or local database). If you find yourself struggling, read through the [official MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) on the subject. It is very thorough and would provide you a good set of understanding (especially if you are newer to automating databases).

Assuming your syntax works correctly on another version of your system, phpMyAdmin should not be giving any errors. If you are not able to get the code working, phpMyAdmin has a native "Create Routines" tool, which you could use to help automate the syntax.

As far as what is apparantly wrong with your code: your nested locate on the eighth line seems to be a little out of place. It seems you are trying to do a strip tags method, perhaps doing a regex match and replace method would simplify your endeavors. There are many MySQL string functions (a reference for which you can find [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_insert)), get creative with your method!

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll see that documentation. And then i'll say something again. Thank you. I what to vote for your answer but i can't. :/